# Either save state of Fragment or save file and update from that - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, download

In my app I have noticed that the user will have a lot of data usage if the fragment keeps unloading and having to get the information from the web again. I have three Action Bar Tabs in my app and when you go to the middle (second) tab the first fragment does not unload but when you go to the third fragment and go back to the first, the first fragment has unloaded and so the app redoes the AsyncTask making it download the information again.

Preferably I would like to change my code so the app loads the information from a file in internal storage which has been downloaded at a previous date and so the user can update this information whenever needed by a Pulltorefresh or something. I am unsure on how I would turn my code into this way and I highly doubt any of you want to spend the time to do that for me so that leads to my next question.

Can you save the state of the fragment to make the app save the state until the third tab instead of the second. I will only ever have three tabs in it so it just needs to be set to that amount and I have looked at some documentation and I am yet to find an answer that works for me. Below is a few of my apps files which may be of some use to you.

List.class (The fragment that keeps getting unloaded)

```
public class List extends Fragment {

    // All static variables
    static final String URL = "http://aspecficwebsite.com/appinfo.xml";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_GAME = "game"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_DATES = "dates";
    static final String KEY_PLATFORMS = "platforms";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";


    ListView list;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList;
    View view;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new TheTask().execute();

            /*
        // Click event for single list row
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
        }); */
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
        //list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.game_list);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
            songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_GAME);
            // looping through all song nodes <song>
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                map.put(KEY_DATES, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DATES));
                map.put(KEY_PLATFORMS, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PLATFORMS));
                map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                songsList.add(map);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
            LazyAdapter adapter = new LazyAdapter(getActivity(), songsList);
            view = getView();
            ListView mlist = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.game_list);
            mlist.setAdapter(adapter);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a viewpager with the tabs if you are not already
Look at this link if you need help with that
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Then with your viewpager do

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

This way none of your tabs will unload when switched.

Answer (score 1):

Kenny C's answer will help with fragments going out of scope.

For internet data, you may want a cache.  Sorry I cannot provide code, but it is pretty straightforward: write a class that you use to fetch all data. Store results locally, perhaps in a file that is named from an md5 hash of the URL.  The next time you fetch the data, first check to see if the file exists:  If so, get the data from the file, otherwise get it from the original source (the internet).  You can also check the date stamp of the file, and if it is old, don't use it anymore.  If you have a lot of files/data, use the Android cache directory so you do not use too much memory.

I am not sure this is what you are looking for, but I hope it points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct to try to find a simple approach to this.

Case 1:
You haven't posted your TabListener code, so firstly I am going to assume that you are adding fragments in onTabSelected and removing them in onTabUnselected. IF this is the case then you should look at using attach and detach instead. The difference is the same instance of the fragment will be used each time you press tab 1.

Case 2:
Based on what you have said (fragment 1 not being destroyed immediately) you may already using attach / detach. If this is the case, then the system may be responsible for destroying fragment 1 as part of its housekeeping. In this case, look at using setRetainInstance(true) for fragment 1. My concern about this approach is that you are updating your UI in this fragment , so you may need to split it into two separate fragments.

In either case, you should consider what you are going to do for an orientation change. If you are happy to lock the orientation initially, you may find that you can get this working quite easily. However, as you know, the better approach is to allow orientation changes and use saveInstanceState.

Post some more information and I will flesh this out a bit, if this answer is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by implementing the FragmentPagerAdapter to keep a cache of the fragments:

```
SparseArray<Fragment> fragment_cache = new SparseArray<Fragment>();
```

Then when the system requests a fragment, I check to see if it's in the cache:

```
    @Override
public Fragment getItem(final int item) {
    // If it's in the cache, give it up.
    final Fragment frag = fragment_cache.get(item);
    if (frag != null) {
        return frag;
    }

    // It needs to be created.
    switch (item) {
    case 0:
        fragment_cache.put(
                0,
                Fragment.instantiate(activity,
                        Page1.class.getName()));
        break;

    case 1:
        fragment_cache.put(1,
                Fragment.instantiate(activity, Page2.class.getName()));
        break;

    default: {
        final Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("toc_child", item - 2);
        fragment_cache.put(item, Fragment.instantiate(activity,
                Page3.class.getName(), b));
    }
        break;
    }

    // The item is definitely in the cache now.
    return fragment_cache.get(item);
}
```

This lets me avoid rebuilding some very large pages all the time.

On the other hand, if you have to drop the activity the fragments are in (or if you have to drop the fragment the ViewPager is in), then you might want to look at building a [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). This will let you abstract your data loading from your UI. Your service won't go away like the UI, so this might be your best bet.

```
   [1] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Data class` that implements `Serializable` with all your varibels, then save and load that object.
If you want to able to alter the data then use a version int or string to check if you need to get the new version of the variables.